# Group by issue in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Been trying to group by the date;

its run just fine but when I try and insert the code into a view it says its invalid.

"ORA-01843: not a valid month"

[image: Here is the current code.]

Comment: Please do not post your code as an image.  It should be placed into a code block with '```' at start and end.

Comment: ...or indent by 4 spaces (e.g. by pressing Control-K).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting what looks like a date as a date?  Just use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(A3_ORDERS.ORDERDATE, 'Month')
```

and the same in the `GROUP BY`.

And then some more advice:

- Do you really want to avoid including the year?  That seems dangerous.
- `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.